# Declaring Scalar variable issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to piece together the Iventory for an item for multiple databases using declare statements to rename some categories. I'm having difficulty identifying

I've written up most of the code but get back this error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11 
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Item".

```
SELECT        dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Bin Type Code], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Item No_], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].Description, 
                         SUM(dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].Quantity) AS Quantity, dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Location Code], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item Status], 
                         dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item UPC_EAN Number], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Vendor No_], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Brand (Dimension)], LEFT(dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].No_, 2) AS Prefix
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry] ON dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].No_ = dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Item No_]
WHERE        (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Inventory Posting Group] = N'FIN_MFG_PR') OR
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Inventory Posting Group] = 'VEND_PROD')
GROUP BY dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Item No_], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Location Code], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].Description, 
                         dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Bin Type Code], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item Status], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item UPC_EAN Number], dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Vendor No_], 
                         dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Brand (Dimension)], LEFT(dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].No_, 2)
HAVING        (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Item No_] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Item) + N'%') AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Brand (Dimension)] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Brand) + N'%') AND 
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Vendor No_] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Vendor) + N'%') AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Bin Type Code] IN (@BinType)) AND 
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Location Code] IN (@Location)) AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item Status] IN (@Status)) AND (LEFT(dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].No_, 2) LIKE '%' + UPPER(@Prefix) 
                         + '%') OR
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Item No_] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Item) + N'%') AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Brand (Dimension)] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Brand) + N'%') AND 
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Vendor No_] LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@Vendor) + N'%') AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Bin Type Code] IN (@BinType)) AND 
                         (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry].[Location Code] IN (@Location)) AND (dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].[Item Status] IN (@Status)) AND (LEFT(dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Item].No_, 2) LIKE '%' + UPPER(@Prefix) 
                         + '%')
```

I should be able to get back the inventory for the item that I specified.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems very clear to me.

Comment: I don't see that you have declared `@Item` in your SQL, as well as the rest of the variables. The error is telling you the problem here.

Comment: `IN (@BinType)` won't do do what you are probably hoping for also. It is equivalent to `= @BinType`. If you are supplying a comma delimited string it won't work as you want

Comment: On a different note, as well. Whitespace, line breaks and aliases are wonderful things. That SQL is far too difficult to read do the the signifcant lack of all of them. And what is that `HAVING` clause? It looks more like a `WHERE`.

Comment: Also, finally, referencing a column with the schema name prior to the table name is deprecated.

Comment: I created this though using Query Designer from a report builder, does this change how I would have to place it in Server Manager?

Comment: I would personally write your query like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f35f8d28c2c42035f8e0e410fd54aa73) (note the comment in regards to the `OR`). This also gets you the same error, showing that you haven't declared your variables/parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed that you have created the script using Query Designer from a report builder, This is understandable that your report has so many parameter that can be selected or insert values using UI before you generates the report. The selected/inserted parameter values are then passed to the Query and query then executes accordingly after replacing the Parameter/variables in the query with selected/inserted value.

The problem is, you are trying to execute the same script in SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO) which is not possible without replacing the variables with there values. You can see in your script that there are numbers of variable placed as - @Item,@Brand,@Vendor and couple more. They are meaningful only when you run the report as reporting engine handle those variable with the values inserted from UI. But as you wants to run the script from SSMS, you must need to Declare all those variables on top of the script and pass necessary values to them to execute the script.

You can declare all variables as below and Once the declaration and value assignment is done, you can now execute your script in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(200) = 'Put Value'
DECLARE @Brand VARCHAR(200) = 'Put Value'
DECLARE @Vendor VARCHAR(200) = 'Put Value'
-- Similar way you need to Declare and assign value to all 
-- other variables used in the script.

SELECT    
dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Warehouse Entry]
....... Rest of the script
```